# Android mock locations from map click don't seem to work

Tags: android, google-maps, unit-testing, google-api, location

I'm developing an application which uses both a Google Map and Google Location Service (for geofences).

For testing, I wanted to make it so that when I click on a point of the map, the Location Client gets a mock location of that point. The relevant parts of the code are these:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    GoogleMap gmap = mMapFragment.getMap();
    gmap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
}

public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLocationClient.setMockMode(true);
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
            ...
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    Location loc = new Location("flp");
    loc.setLatitude(point.latitude);
    loc.setLongitude(point.longitude);
    loc.setAccuracy(1);
    loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mLocationClient.setMockLocation(loc);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Touch " + loc.getLatitude() + " - " + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "LocChange " + loc.getLatitude() + " - " + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The Map Click Listener works: when I touch the map, I get the "Touch" toast.
The Location Listener works too: if I don't activate the mock mode of the location client, it receives normal location updates from GPS (which show "LocChange" toasts).

If I activate the mock mode, though, I only get "Touch" toasts and not "LocChange" ones. Gofences aren't activated either.
This leads me to believe that the problem is somehow in the sending/receiving of the mock locations.

Is there something I missed...?

Comment: Why not use Genymotion for testing, it a good emulator with location services support, much easy to use.